# Weekly View Diary - Go to Specific date

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a diary view, it all seems to work well, however, I want to be able to make the diary view go to a specified date using some vba.

Currently, I have a week on show, a next week and previous week buttons, this changes the view by 1 week either way.

I would like to have a button that allows the user to click, specify a date and have the weekly view show the week that contains that date.

I don't have any code at this point, as I have no idea where to start.  the code for the next week button is below along with an image of the current weekly view.  Hope this helps answer my question.

```
Sub NextWeek()
    Dim viewerCol, viewerRow As Long
    StopCalc
     viewerRow = 2

    With Sheet8
        For viewerCol = 4 To 10
        .Cells(viewerRow, viewerCol).value = .Cells(viewerRow, viewerCol).value + 7
        Next
    End With
    ResetCalc
    WeeklyProjectView_Load
End Sub
```

View of columns B:M, D:J contain Monday:Sunday

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub WeekContainingDay()
    
    Dim InputDay As Date
    Dim ViewerCol As Byte
    Dim ViewerRow As Byte
    
    'StopCalc
    
    ViewerRow = 2
    InputDay = InputBox("Type date in desired week", "Week Selection", Format(Date, "dd mmm"))
    
    Do Until Weekday(InputDay, vbMonday) = 1
        InputDay = InputDay - 1
        Debug.Print InputDay
    Loop
    
    With Sheet8
        For ViewerCol = 4 To 10
            .Cells(ViewerRow, ViewerCol).Value = InputDay + ViewerCol - 4
        Next ViewerCol
    End With
    
    'ResetCalc
    'WeeklyProjectView_Load
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, I hope you don't mind, but I amended it to create a "go to today" button too.

Comment: No reason I would mind.